# Timing assertion in testcafe

Tags: node.js, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have several testcases in a suite for testcafe. And when I run this in QA environment say I get a report like this

TC1 -- 5 secs
TC2- 4 secs
TC3- 10 secs

So each test case is taking different time to complete( best case scenario) Now in production also I want the test case to run in the same amount of time say TC1 in Production should not take more than 5 secs, how do I code that in testcafe?
Is there an assertion which will allow me to monitor the test case completion within a particular time? I want full testcase completion, not selector or assertion completion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you try the [TestCafe Programming Interface](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/programming-interface/). In this case you can separate all your tests into "lists" and add your own "run-done" logic. See the following "one-run" example:

```
const createTestCafe = require('testcafe');
let testcafe         = null;

createTestCafe('localhost', 1337, 1338)
    .then(tc => {
        testcafe       = tc;
        const runner   = testcafe.createRunner();
        const testList = ['tests/fixture1.js', 'tests/func/fixture3.js'];

        const runPromise = runner
            .src(testList)
            .browsers(['chrome'])
            .run();

        const deadlinePromise = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 10000))
            .then(throw new Error('fail'));

        return Promise.race(runPromise, deadlinePromise).
    })
    .then(() => {
        // success
    })
    .catch(() => {
        // fail
    });
```

Comment: thank you, this looks like exactly what i want but whatever test i am trying its taking 12 or 15 secs where as in the deadlinePromise i have put SetTimeout as 10000, still testcases are coming pass. am i doing anything wrong here? if the tests are taking 12 or 15secs since i have put Promice.race i should get a failure correct?

Comment: Promice.race doesn't terminate late promises and it just ignores their results. So, an error thrown on the deadline timeout doesn't affect testcases. They are passed anyway. The difference is that where you finish - in the `then` or `catch` block.